# swift 3: Type 'Any?' has no subscript members

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I keep getting this error for my graph requests??

> Type 'Any?' has no subscript members

the error points at result.... this only happened when I converted to swift 3... anybody????

```
 let nextrequest: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/friends", parameters: ["fields": "name, id, gender"], httpMethod: "GET")
            nextrequest.start { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                guard let listOfFriends = result["data"] as? [AnyObject] else {
                    return
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
let nextrequest: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"me/friends", parameters: ["fields": "name, id, gender"], httpMethod: "GET")
    nextrequest.start { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
         guard let result = result as? [String:[AnyObject]], let listOfFriends = result["data"]  else {
        return
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### A little explanation

> In Swift 3, the Value type of NSDictionary, NSArray, etc. have been
> changed to Any. So the result type of subscript result[key] is Any?,
> which cannot be automatically converted to AnyObject.

You have to explicitly cast into `[String:[AnyObject]]` type before using the result.

Try using,

```
let tResult = result as? [String:[AnyObject]]
guard let listOfFriends = tResult["data"] else { return; }
```

as mentioned in the answer of @xhmar