# 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no subscript members error swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I've updated Xcode from 7 to 8 and Swift from 2.3 to 3.

error :

Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no subscript members

```
var posts = NSMutableArray()    
let lista: [(IdM:String, Nombre: String)] = posts.map
        {
            if let idM = $0["IdM"] as? String, let nombre = $0["Nombre"] as? String
            {
                let element = (idM,nombre)
                return element
            }
            return nil
        }.flatMap{$0}
```

I need help please

Comment: Declare post as `var posts = [[String: Any]]()`

Comment: thank you very much served me your help, I appreciate your comment. Thank you

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549107/swift-3-type-any-has-no-subscript-members/39549477#39549477