# 'NSFastEnumerator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no subscript members

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

I was going through this [appcoda blog](https://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/) and came across a function where I have to get indices of visible rows. I am learning and implementing `Swift 3` / `Xcode 8`. I get `No subscript members` error for the following function.

```
func getIndicesOfVisibleRows() {
    visibleRowsPerSection.removeAll()

    for currentSectionCells in cellDescriptors {
        var visibleRows = [Int]()

        for row in 0...((currentSectionCells as! [[String: AnyObject]]).count - 1) {
            if currentSectionCells[row]["isVisible"] as! Bool == true { //Get compile time error here
                visibleRows.append(row)
            }
        }

        visibleRowsPerSection.append(visibleRows)
    }
}
```

How do I get object of `currentSectionCells` array whose object for key is "`isVisible`" here?

Comment: Are you sure there are **two** for loops?

Comment: @vadian: Yes there are two for loops. Please refer the function in the linked blog.

Comment: I cannot understand that **Swift** tutorials still suggest unrelated collection types like `MSMutableArray` and ugly old-fashioned C-style loops. There are much better and more efficient ways in Swift.

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549107/swift-3-type-any-has-no-subscript-members/39549477#39549477

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the type of your array `cellDescriptors` to `[[[String:Any]]]`  like this way.

```
for currentSectionCells in cellDescriptors.objectEnumerator().allObjects as! [[[String:Any]]]{
    var visibleRows = [Int]()

    for row in 0..<currentSectionCells.count {
        if currentSectionCells[row]["isVisible"] as! Bool == true { 
            visibleRows.append(row)
        }
    }
    visibleRowsPerSection.append(visibleRows)
}
```

Comment: get a warning: Cast from 'NSMutableArray!' to unrelated type '[[[String : Any]]]' always fails

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for currentSectionCells in cellDescriptors as! [[String: AnyObject]] {
```

And

```
for row in 0...currentSectionCells.count - 1 {
```

Comment: 1. Warning: caste to 'NSMutableArray!' to unrelated type '[[String: AnyObject]]' always fails 2. Error: Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

Comment: How is `cellDescriptors` declared?

Comment: var cellDescriptors: NSMutableArray!

Comment: Try: `var cellDescriptors:[[String: AnyObject]]!` and `for currentSectionCells in cellDescriptors{`

Comment: I cannot load the array with this declaration though. I am using cellDescriptors = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: path); to load the array. I still get the ambiguous compiler error reference to member 'subscript in 'if' condition

Answer (score 0):

func getIndicesOfVisibleRows() {
        visibleRowsPerSection.removeAll()

```
    for currentSectionCells in cellDescriptors {
        print(currentSectionCells)
        var visibleRows = [Int]()

        for row in 0...((currentSectionCells as AnyObject).count - 1) {

            if (currentSectionCells as AnyObject).objectAt(row)["isVisible"] as! Bool == true {
                visibleRows.append(row)
            }
        }

        visibleRowsPerSection.append(visibleRows)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more thing you can do is, create your cellDescriptors as a specific swift array as below.

```
var cellDescriptors: [[[String: Any]]]!
```

and load your cellDescriptor from .plist file as below.

```
cellDescriptors = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: path)! as NSArray as! [[[String: Any]]]
```

Now, your code (Mentioned on question) will work as it is, without any changes!