# Type Any has no subscript members Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to convert a function to make it Swift 3.0 compatible. Had to change the parameter `json` from `AnyObject` to `Any`:

```
fileprivate func checkForAuthorizationFailure(_ json: Any) -> Bool {

        let responseMessage = json["response"]! as? String
        if responseMessage == "Unauthorized. Invalid token or email." {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }
```

However at the line: `let responseMessage = json["response"]! as? String` I am now getting the error: ***"Type Any has no subscript members"***. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549107/swift-3-type-any-has-no-subscript-members/39549477#39549477

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to cast Any to AnyObject before using subscript.

```
fileprivate func checkForAuthorizationFailure(_ json: Any) -> Bool {

    let responseMessage = (json as AnyObject)["response"]! as? String
    if responseMessage == "Unauthorized. Invalid token or email." {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```