# Swift 3 Error - Type Any has no subscript members

Tags: xcode, swift3

I recently converted my code to Swift 3 and these errors have popped up. I have no clue what the following error means.

> Type 'Any' has no subscript members

I have tried to change [String: AnyObject] to other types but it has not worked. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641676/type-any-has-no-subscript-members-swift-3-0

Comment: There are 10 questions in the "Related" section with exactly the same title ... but how did you manage to run Xcode 3(!) on a current macOS?

Comment: @MartinR I think OP is talking about Swift 3 and Xcode 8

Comment: @NiravD: That was my (failed?) attempt to be *ironic* :)

Comment: I have looked at other answers and tried type casting in different forms, but I still don't understand where the error comes from and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

> [This Other Stack Overflow Question Might Be Helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641676/type-any-has-no-subscript-members-swift-3-0)

(From the link)

```
let responseMessage = json["response"]! as? String
```

Must be changed to

```
let responseMessage = (json as AnyObject)["response"]! as? String
```

The array must be cast as AnyObject.