# Type 'NSDictionary!' has no subscript members Swift - 3.0 conversion issue

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, swift3

I am getting this compiler error below after auto conversion from Swift 2 to Swift 3,

> Type 'NSDictionary!' has no subscript members

I have seen similar question in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641676/type-any-has-no-subscript-members-swift-3-0), but still the solution is not supposed to work for NSDictionary.

Please let me know how to fix it.

Code:

```
fileprivate var allData:NSDictionary!;
.
.
.
open func getData(_ key:String) -> AnyObject?
{
    return allData[key]; // error in this line
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3, the Value type of `NSDictionary` has been changed to `Any`.
So the result type of subscript `allData[key]` is `Any?`, which cannot be automatically converted to `AnyObject?`.

Try this:

```
open func getData(_ key: String) -> AnyObject?
{
    return allData[key] as AnyObject?
}
```

But, if you use your `allData` as shown, why don't you declare it as `[String: AnyObject]` ?

And the error message... Better send a [bug report](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).

Comment: Thanks @OOPer, it works. Actually its a legacy code, right now i just need to convert to Swift 3. I don't know why dictionary has been used instead. I will refactor when i get time.