# type 'Any' has no subscript members

Tags: swift, swift3

```
let employerName = snapshot.value! ["employerName"] as! String
let employerImage = snapshot.value! ["employerImage"] as! String
let uid = snapshot.value! ["uid"] as! String
```

I reviewed previous posts but cannot seem to find a way to solve this problem. All three lines of code give the "type 'Any' has no subscript members" error. Fairly new to this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: how is snapshot declared? it is related to firebase? did you search for your answer on SO before posting it here?

Comment: Hello. Yes- Firebase and yes I reviewed answers here on SO. Perhaps I am integrating the answers wrong? Like I said, I am fairly new. Any help/suggestions to a particular answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swift 3: Type 'Any?' has no subscript members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549107/swift-3-type-any-has-no-subscript-members)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`snapshot.value` has a type of `Any`. A subscript is a special kind of function that uses the syntax of enclosing a value in braces. This subscript function is implemented by `Dictionary`.

So what is happening here is that YOU as the developer know that `snapshot.value` is a `Dictionary`, but the compiler doesn't. It won't let you call the `subscript` function because you are trying to call it on a value of type `Any` and `Any` does not implement `subscript`. In order to do this, you have to tell the compiler that your `snapshot.value` is actually a `Dictionary`. Further more `Dictionary` lets you use the subscript function with values of whatever type the `Dictionary`'s keys are. So you need to tell it you have a `Dictionary` with keys as `String`(AKA `[String: Any]`). Going even further than that, in your case, you seem to know that all of the values in your `Dictionary` are `String` as well, so instead of casting each value after you subscript it to `String` using `as! String`, if you just tell it that your `Dictionary` has keys and values that are both `String` types (AKA `[String: String]`), then you will be able to subscript to access the values and the compiler will know the values are `String` also!

```
guard let snapshotDict = snapshot.value as? [String: String] else {
    // Do something to handle the error 
    // if your snapshot.value isn't the type you thought it was going to be. 
}

let employerName = snapshotDict["employerName"]
let employerImage = snapshotDict["employerImage"]
let uid = snapshotDict["fid"]
```

And there you have it!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to treat `snapshot.value` as an unwrapped dictionary, try casting to one and, if it succeeds, use that dictionary.

Consider something like:

```
func findElements(candidate: Any) {
    if let dict: [String : String] = candidate as? Dictionary {
        print(dict["employerName"])
        print(dict["employerImage"])
        print(dict["uid"])
    }
}

// Fake call    
let snapshotValue = ["employerName" : "name", "employerImage" : "image", "uid" : "345"]
findElements(snapshotValue)
```