# Getting specific value from Swift array

Tags: arrays, json, swift

So, I'm download data from an API using SwiftyJSON. I'm converting it, and looping through to get all of the results. I'm trying to get a specific part of each result to print out, but I can't seem to get it working.

The code I'm using below takes the json, and loops through it and prints out what is also below. From what is printed, I just want to get the "subject".

```
do {
            let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
            let json = JSON(jsonObj)


            let pms: NSArray = json["result"]["pms"].arrayValue as NSArray


            let arrayLength = pms.count

            for var i in (0..<arrayLength) {
                let pm = pms[i]

                i+=1

            }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
```

Which then gives values like:

```
{
  "subject" : "Example",
  "status" : 1,
  "recipient" : 012345,
  "recipientusername" : "Example",
  "dateline" : "2018-01-01",
  "sender" : 012345,
  "pmid" : 012345,
  "senderusername" : "DoctorSheep"
}
{
  "subject" : "Example 2",
  "status" : 1,
  "recipient" : 678910,
  "recipientusername" : "Example 2",
  "dateline" : "2018-01-01",
  "sender" : 678910,
  "pmid" : 678910,
  "senderusername" : "Example 2"
}
```

If I try something like

```
let subject = pm["subject"]
```

I get an error that "Type 'Any' has no subscript members".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [type 'Any' has no subscript members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903204/type-any-has-no-subscript-members)

Comment: Few things to note. in Swift don't use NS values unless you have to. Use the Swift Version NSArray = Array. Use the Codable protocol to help with JSON parsing, then just iterate over the array and get the subject value

Comment: Wow, that simple thing you just told me fixed it.

Comment: I'll make an edit now to show.

Answer (score 0):

```
let pms = json["result"]["pms"].arrayValue as Array


let arrayLength = pms.count

for var i in (0..<arrayLength) {
    let pm = pms[i]
    let subject = pm["subject"]
    print(subject)
    i+=1
}
```