# Swift 3 NSMuttableArray

Tags: nsmutablearray, swift3

I'll vey appreciate you for your help.
I am declare new new empty array:

var cellDescriptors = Any

but when i try to use it in somewhere, i am always receive the same error = "Type 'any' has no subscript members".

For example:

```
var cellDescriptors = [Any]()
var visibleRowsPerSection = [[Int]]()

func loadCellDescriptors() {
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "CellDescriptor", ofType: "plist") {
cellDescriptors = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: path)as AnyObject?
    getIndicesOfVisibleRows()
    tblExpandable.reloadData()
```

I read a lot and find that were some changes in Swift 3.0.1, but i can't understand, which changes i need to do , to fix it.

I tried to use the following: [swift 3: Type 'Any?' has no subscript members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549107/swift-3-type-any-has-no-subscript-members/39549477#39549477)

But unfortunately its not working in my case.
Tried to use [AnyHashable:Any] as well.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You shouldn't generally be using NSMutableArray in Swift. Aside from that, what line is the error on?

Comment: what i need to use? error appears on line "let myArray =..."

Comment: ok. I think i know what is a problem, but i don't know how its connected to swift 3. if i have an array if dictionaries, how can i get a value for specific key of specific dictionary?

Comment: What's the declaration of `cellDescriptors`?

Comment: Can you please edit that into your question so that it has proper syntax highlighting?

Comment: sure. i update the code. thank you very much for your help! the PLIST file is an array of dictionaries.

Comment: Do you know what "subscripting" means?

Comment: "subscripts" are shortcuts for accessing the member elements of a collection.

Comment: Why did you remove your original code from the question?

Comment: You're trying to subscript something that the compiler doesn't know is a Collection. `cellDescriptors` is a `[Any]`, `cellDescriptors[indexPath.section]` is an `Any`, and you're trying to subscript that `Any`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations!!! I tried to change the `cellDescriptors` to NSMutableArray, but I am receiving the same error. I am trying to read carrefully the documentation, but no matter what i change - got the same error. What i am missing? Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: First of all, don't us `NSMutableArray` in Swift. You need to declare your `cellDescriptors` as `Array<Array<Something>>` (a.k.a. `[[Something]]`), so that when you subscript it once by `indexPath.section`, you get an `Array<Something>` (a.k.a. `[Something]). Finally, you can subscript it once more to get your `Something`. Change Something to whatever type you're actually dealing with

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help and time! it was very useful!!!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer so you can mark this question as answered

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to subscript something that the compiler doesn't know is a `Collection`. `cellDescriptors` is a `[Any]`, `cellDescriptors[indexPath.section]` is an `Any`, and you're trying to subscript that `Any`.

First of all, don't us `NSMutableArray` in Swift. You need to declare your `cellDescriptors` as `Array<Array<Something>>` (a.k.a. `[[Something]]`), so that when you subscript it once by `indexPath.section`, you get an `Array<Something>` (a.k.a. `[Something]`). Finally, you can subscript it once more to get your `Something`. Change `Something` to whatever type you're actually dealing with.